# Prevent NHibernate mapping property to a proxy

Tags: nhibernate

I am searching around for a solution to my problem but all I get is the reasons this does happen as opposed to preventing if from happening.

I have a class, `WorkflowActivityInstance` which has a collection of `WorkflowActivityInstanceTransitions` which represents the transitioning of the state of the workflow. The transitions are mapped in a `Transitions` property fine.

Therefore: `WorkflowActivityInstance` <-- `WorkflowActivityInstanceTransition`

I would like a view on the object which would give the `WorkflowActivityInstance` state including its current state, which would simply be the latest `WorkflowActivityInstanceTransition` without having the user-coder to perform their own sorting and selection on the `Transitions` property.

Originally, I had:

```
public virtual IWorkflowActivityInstanceTransition CurrentState
{
    get { return Transitions.OrderBy(q => q.TransitionTimeStamp).LastOrDefault(); }
}
```

But I just get:

> NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException:
>   NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be
>   used as proxies:
>   FB.SimpleWorkflow.NHibernate.Model.WorkflowActivityInstance: method
>   CurrentState should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected
>   internal virtual'.

I tried to be cheeky and convert this to a method:

```
public IWorkflowActivityInstanceTransition GetCurrentState()
{
    return Transitions.OrderBy(q => q.TransitionTimeStamp).LastOrDefault();
}
```

But I get a very similar:

> NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException:
>   NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be
>   used as proxies:
>   FB.SimpleWorkflow.NHibernate.Model.WorkflowActivityInstance: method
>   GetCurrentState should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected
>   internal virtual'.

I would like to keep the very simple behaviour of `CurrentState` in my model class, and prevent NHibernate from over-reaching itself and trying to map/proxy this property. It feels that this should just be an attribute on the property I don't want to map ...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15):

NHibernate needs to override all public, protected and internal methods, otherwise proxies can't work (it would be possible for your code to access a not yet initialized proxy).

I can't see a reason why your property wouldn't work, but the error is very clear for your method, you miss the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it needs to override my members for proxy purposes, particularly for lazy loading purposes. However, this particular member is not to be persisted, and therefore NHibernate has no business proxying it. Am I to understand I can't add anything outside of the model in the model, even for convenience purposes?

Comment: @Program.X You can add whatever properties or methods you want, they just have to be virtual. As I already explained, NHibernate needs to overwrite all properties and methods, not only mapped/persisted ones.

Answer (score 1):

You must to use **virtual** keyword. This is how it work of Nhibernate. And also this page will help you.

[Github nhibernate/nhibernate-core](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/d506d3c80f1684f3864ce77692dfb286dc98c93d/src/NHibernate/InvalidProxyTypeException.cs#L12)